# JavaFX get minimum width/height/size of a Pane before it starts clipping

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

FFor the sake of simplicity it is better to show you the problem and then describe it
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I plan to set the minimum width of the window to the minimum size possible before the pane (groupPane in this example) starts being clipped

how can i calculate that width beforehand.

the fxml section :

[image]

the current calculation method:

```
public void setupMinStageSizeInStandardMode(Stage primaryStage, Scene scene)
{
    // the thickness of the border of the window
    ObjectBinding<Insets> insets = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
                    new Insets(scene.getY(),
                            primaryStage.getWidth()-scene.getWidth() - scene.getX(),
                            primaryStage.getHeight()-scene.getHeight() - scene.getY(),
                            scene.getX()),
            scene.xProperty(),
            scene.yProperty(),
            scene.widthProperty(),
            scene.heightProperty(),
            primaryStage.widthProperty(),
            primaryStage.heightProperty()
    );

    //i am trying to get the grid to the smallest size here
    controlsGrid.setMaxWidth(0);
    controlsGrid.setPrefWidth(0);

    // then i am trying to calculate the wanted size
    double minStageWidth = controlsGrid.getWidth() +insets.get().getLeft() + insets.get().getRight();
    double minStageHeight = controlsGrid.getHeight() +insets.get().getTop() + insets.get().getBottom();

    System.out.println(minStageWidth);
    System.out.println(minStageHeight);

    //then return the grid to it's intended size
    controlsGrid.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    controlsGrid.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    primaryStage.setMinHeight(minStageHeight);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(minStageWidth);
}
```

Please help. i am losing sleep over this...

Comment: What happens if you set `minWidth` to `USE_COMPUTED`, and then call `getMinWidth`? I would assume that would work...

Comment: @sillyfly that doesn't seem to work. if i do that, it is returning 17 pixels. it's probably 9x2 for the borders + -1 (USE_COMPUTED_SIZE = -1)

Comment: Seems to me you need to figure out or set the `minWidth`s of the six components you have. I suggest you set your `minWidth` for each component. Then you should set the `minWidth` on the `Stage` equal to the sum of the components `minWidth`s.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson that goes against the concept of leaving the component handling to the layouts. I don't want to give my components minimum width. i just want to know the minimu width they will take with out actually resizing them

Comment: anything new? I am still stuck here

Comment: 5 years later and there's still no easy way to do this. What I do is set the min size manually on the root node, then call minWidth(-1) and minHeight(-1) on it, add the computed window borders and setMinWidth()/setMinHeight() those values on the stage. MUI on the Amiga did it automatically 30 years ago. This is sad.